# Need to adapt a regex without "+" in Group

Tags: regex

I'm having some issue to create the following regex :

```
/schools/65896
/schools/98542/Teacher
/schools/85124/Classe
/schools/45684/Student
/schools/Abcdefggg/Student
```

Capture only the number or the name after /schools/ :

```
65896 
98542 
85124 
45684 
Abcdefggg
```

This Regex works :

```
\/schools\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

But unfortunately I'm not allowed to use "+" inside the group.

Any idea of other ways to do it ?

Many Thanks

Comment: *I'm not allowed to use "+" inside the group* - why? Is the regex used in some POSIX BRE regex tool?

Comment: Why are you not allowed? Are you not allowed to use anything else? What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regexes are (almost) identical to the original, but + is not used:

```
\/schools\/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)
\/schools\/([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})
```

Comment: No, `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` is not equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`. `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*` is.

Comment: They are NOT identical, true, that is why I stated `(almost)`. Thanks for the hint on how on re-write it. +1